# Symfony routing using database

Tags: database, symfony, routes

I need to do Symfony routing using database.

Example here:

URL: domain.com/manufacturer/product/. I want the router to execute query to the database and based on that decide which Controller to use (e.g. SELECT controller FROM routing WHERE url = 'manufacturer/product/')

I also would like to have an Action and parameters passed.

I have already read Symfony documentation, studied routing bundles and CMF component but nothing really fits to my problem. Tried also to adjust Router.php class - generate() and match() functions, but that is not very clean solution..

Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want some code to executed before a controller is called and after the route is determined you must use before filters in symfony from the [docs](http://symfony.com/doc/2.8/cookbook/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html)